# CouchDB Replication Issue

Tags: couchdb

We are new to CouchDB and are using it to provide a cloud database which we then replicate onto a ReactNative mobile app running PouchDB. This is working correctly in our dev and test environments, but we are struggling to get the production environment working correctly as we want additional resilience in production.

In Production all hosted in AWS we have 2 EC2 instances running CouchDB in docker instances, they are setup as a cluster and we have our database replicating between them happily. In front of the ec2 instances we have an application load balancer listening on port 5984 and routing the traffic to the EC2 instances, which also have the ports 5984 exposed and mapped.

When we have a single EC2 instance setup in the cluster the mobile app is able to replicate data and the app works perfectly, however if we then add in a second instance then all replications fail. It makes no difference which instance we use when there is only 1 instance.

Any help resolving greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Simon, a CouchDB cluster requires at least 3 nodes, 2 node cluster is not supported. Do you have a cluster or two single nodes with a continuous replication of a database between them?

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seem the recommendation for 3 nodes in the documentation. As it was setup when I wrote this doc we just had 2 single nodes which were replicating the data across them, I have since reconfigured it and have got the full clustering working correctly.

Comment: In case anyone needs it, the bit I missed was setting the Erlang cookie and explicitly setting the password to a specific hash that was the same on all instances.